# How to create album and upload photos to page by anyone in FB? ( php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

.>< as the title

I want to build a application that can let anyone create the album and upload photos in it **on my own page**.

But I completely seek in the fb's develop document, it doesn't have the api to let anyone create it if you are't the page owner.

so I think maybe I can use php curl auto login my acconunt and then use my account to create and uplaod.

But in this case I use curl login my account ,is it safe?
or who can tell me the best solution?

thank you >M< plz bear me If my description or English grammar is awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use PHP to authenticate your account and have your web app act as you, but doing this is actually a violation of Facebook's Developer Agreement. If you do this, you will certainly need to be very careful not to let users see your password or user id.

My best advice is to not put them in your PHP scripts. Instead place them in an encrypted file outside of your web directory. The file should be encrypted with one of the symetric encryption methods in the phpseclib. (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)

The key you are using should also be in a file that is stored outside of your web directory.

Comment: thanks for answering>3<
wow , it'll violate Facebook's Developer Agreement

Comment: From https://developers.facebook.com/policy/, 2) You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects Facebook usernames or passwords. In this case you will be proxying. I'm sure Facebook would claim many other violations if you came to their attention. If you do not generate a lot of traffic, they'd probably never know.

Comment: oh  ~  I see maybe I must think another solution but not use curl to built it. thanks a lot ><

Comment: BTW FB hasn't give develops the function that can post photo on the fan page even if the page open the post of photo function right?